# Solaris: PKG - Script To Verify All Packages Except for a Few

Tags: awk, scripting, solaris

I'm trying to verify the all packages except for a pre-defined list of packages that I know are going to fail for known reasons. This script is going to be run on all Solaris systems within our environment to confirm a system baseline.

I'm open to any technique which will work here, and is possible to put on a single line (Limitation of the tool I'm using for validation).

My initial thought was that I'd take a pkg list, run it through AWK to grab the package name, filter out the packages I don't want, and then run an individual pkg verify on each package remaining individually.

This is the code I've created below:

```
pkg list | awk 'BEGIN {c=0} $1 == "exclude1" || $1 == "exclude2" { next } { system("pkg verify " $1); c++ } END { if (c == 0) print "none" }'
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm not seeing any output even though I know there should be a few things that fail the pkg verify.

I thought the system( would capture the output, but I'm relatively new to AWK, and it could be I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solaris 11.3, you will want to use `nawk` rather than `awk`.  `nawk` ("new `awk`") is installed by default and should be in your path (`/usr/bin/nawk`).

The `system()` function in `awk` (any implementation) does not return the output of the command, but its exit code.  This is ok though, as you probably don't want the actual output from `pkg` anyway.  The `pkg` command will exit with a non-zero exit code if something went wrong (see the `pkg` manual).

The following pipeline will take the `pkg list` output and skip the first line (which is a header), and all lines matching the excluded package names. For the remaining lines of input, it will execute `pkg verify` through `system()` with the package name.

If `pkg verify` returns a non-zero exit status, it will increment a counter. At the end of processing, the counter will be displayed, showing how many verification errors occurred.

```
pkg list | nawk 'NR > 1 && !/exclude1|exclude2/ { if (system("pkg verify " $1)) { e++ } } END { printf("%d errors\n", e) }'
```

This is rather inefficient though. It's quicker to get a list of the packages and verify them in one go:

```
pkg list | nawk 'NR > 1 && !/exclude1|exclude2/ { print $1 }' | ( xargs pkg verify ) || echo "there were errors"
```

If you have a list of packages to ignore in a file:

```
pkg list | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -F -v -f excluded.txt | nawk 'NR > 1 { print }' | ( xargs pkg verify ) || echo "there were errors"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to use gawk instead o awk.

Simple test:

```
# pkg list|awk '{system("pkg verify $1")}'
# 

# pkg list|gawk '{system("pkg verify $1")}'
PACKAGE                                                                 STATUS
pkg://solaris/driver/storage/ssd                                         ERROR
```

Comment: When I run this on Solaris its like I just ran:
pkg verify

With no parameters. It doesn't appear to be checking each package individually, which is what I need in order to be able to put a "filter" in the middle and remove some packages from the check.

Comment: Aka, its running "package verify" on all the packages multiple times.